# Select item from javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need some help getting some details of this array and save it into a variable. I'd like to be able to have the latitude and longitude saved as individual variables. I'm really terrible at selecting pieces of an array.

```
autofillCollection.addEventListener('retrieve', (event) => {
  const featureCollection = event.detail;
  const inputEl = event.target;
  console.log(featureCollection);
```

and getting this as a Response, but I'd like to store the latitude and logintude coordinates as variables. I'm terrible at mapping arrays. Can anyone help me select the coordinates indivudally?

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "accuracy": "rooftop",
        "match_code": {
          "exact_match": false,
          "house_number": "UNMATCHED",
          "street": "UNMATCHED",
          "postcode": "UNMATCHED",
          "place": "UNMATCHED",
          "region": "UNMATCHED",
          "locality": "NOT_APPLICABLE",
          "country": "INFERRED",
          "confidence": "low"
        },
        "place_type": [
          "address"
        ],
        "place_name": "3329 Old Georgetowne Road, Edmond, Oklahoma 73013, United States",
        "address_number": "3329",
        "street": "Old Georgetowne Road",
        "context": [
          {
            "id": "postcode.250457836",
            "text_en": "73013",
            "text": "73013"
          },
          {
            "id": "place.97216748",
            "wikidata": "Q862645",
            "text_en": "Edmond",
            "language_en": "en",
            "text": "Edmond",
            "language": "en"
          },
          {
            "id": "district.17426156",
            "wikidata": "Q485038",
            "text_en": "Oklahoma County",
            "language_en": "en",
            "text": "Oklahoma County",
            "language": "en"
          },
          {
            "id": "region.304364",
            "short_code": "US-OK",
            "wikidata": "Q1649",
            "text_en": "Oklahoma",
            "language_en": "en",
            "text": "Oklahoma",
            "language": "en"
          },
          {
            "id": "country.8940",
            "short_code": "us",
            "wikidata": "Q30",
            "text_en": "United States",
            "language_en": "en",
            "text": "United States",
            "language": "en"
          }
        ],
        "id": "address.3132590889692730",
        "external_ids": {
          "carmen": "address.3132590889692730",
          "federated": "carmen.address.3132590889692730"
        },
        "feature_name": "3329 Old Georgetowne Road",
        "matching_name": "3329 Old Georgetowne Road",
        "description": "Edmond, Oklahoma 73013, United States",
        "metadata": {
          "iso_3166_2": "US-OK",
          "iso_3166_1": "us"
        },
        "language": "en",
        "maki": "marker",
        "postcode": "73013",
        "place": "Edmond",
        "district": "Oklahoma County",
        "region": "Oklahoma",
        "region_code": "OK",
        "country": "United States",
        "country_code": "us",
        "full_address": "3329 Old Georgetowne Road, Edmond, Oklahoma 73013, United States",
        "address_line1": "3329 Old Georgetowne Road",
        "address_line2": "",
        "address_line3": "",
        "address_level1": "OK",
        "address_level2": "Edmond",
        "address_level3": "",
        "postcode_plus": "0802",
        "is_deliverable": true,
        "missing_unit": false
      },
      "text_en": "Old Georgetowne Road",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -97.46885,
          35.62264
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "attribution": "NOTICE: © 2022 Mapbox and its suppliers. All rights reserved. Use of this data is subject to the Mapbox Terms of Service (https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/). This response and the information it contains may not be retained. POI(s) provided by Foursquare."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map` on the main object property `features` on each feature's `geometry` object's `coordinates` property, then flatten the arrays into one with the individual coordinates using `Array.flat`, each array element will be an individual coordinate, so you can use them as a single variable:

```js
const test = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "accuracy": "rooftop",
        "match_code": {
          "exact_match": false,
          "house_number": "UNMATCHED",
          "street": "UNMATCHED",
          "postcode": "UNMATCHED",
          "place": "UNMATCHED",
          "region": "UNMATCHED",
          "locality": "NOT_APPLICABLE",
          "country": "INFERRED",
          "confidence": "low"
        },
        "place_type": [
          "address"
        ],
        "place_name": "3329 Old Georgetowne Road, Edmond, Oklahoma 73013, United States",
        "address_number": "3329",
        "street": "Old Georgetowne Road",
        "context": [
          {
            "id": "postcode.250457836",
            "text_en": "73013",
            "text": "73013"
          },
          {
            "id": "place.97216748",
            "wikidata": "Q862645",
            "text_en": "Edmond",
            "language_en": "en",
            "text": "Edmond",
            "language": "en"
          },
          {
            "id": "district.17426156",
            "wikidata": "Q485038",
            "text_en": "Oklahoma County",
            "language_en": "en",
            "text": "Oklahoma County",
            "language": "en"
          },
          {
            "id": "region.304364",
            "short_code": "US-OK",
            "wikidata": "Q1649",
            "text_en": "Oklahoma",
            "language_en": "en",
            "text": "Oklahoma",
            "language": "en"
          },
          {
            "id": "country.8940",
            "short_code": "us",
            "wikidata": "Q30",
            "text_en": "United States",
            "language_en": "en",
            "text": "United States",
            "language": "en"
          }
        ],
        "id": "address.3132590889692730",
        "external_ids": {
          "carmen": "address.3132590889692730",
          "federated": "carmen.address.3132590889692730"
        },
        "feature_name": "3329 Old Georgetowne Road",
        "matching_name": "3329 Old Georgetowne Road",
        "description": "Edmond, Oklahoma 73013, United States",
        "metadata": {
          "iso_3166_2": "US-OK",
          "iso_3166_1": "us"
        },
        "language": "en",
        "maki": "marker",
        "postcode": "73013",
        "place": "Edmond",
        "district": "Oklahoma County",
        "region": "Oklahoma",
        "region_code": "OK",
        "country": "United States",
        "country_code": "us",
        "full_address": "3329 Old Georgetowne Road, Edmond, Oklahoma 73013, United States",
        "address_line1": "3329 Old Georgetowne Road",
        "address_line2": "",
        "address_line3": "",
        "address_level1": "OK",
        "address_level2": "Edmond",
        "address_level3": "",
        "postcode_plus": "0802",
        "is_deliverable": true,
        "missing_unit": false
      },
      "text_en": "Old Georgetowne Road",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -97.46885,
          35.62264
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "attribution": "NOTICE: © 2022 Mapbox and its suppliers. All rights reserved. Use of this data is subject to the Mapbox Terms of Service (https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/). This response and the information it contains may not be retained. POI(s) provided by Foursquare."
};

const coordinates = test.features.map((a) => a.geometry.coordinates);
console.log(coordinates.flat());
console.log(...coordinates.flat());
```